# Any simple way to do for loop pipe , such as ` ls | grep ".*.7z" | 7z -e {}`

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am curious that is there an function/command to cope for loop pipe ?

It is easy to occur below demand

1. you run a command return multiple line
2. you need process each line
3. pass each line to another function/command

For example:

you need find some path match a parttern , move each to another place :

```bsh
# 1.
find path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec mv -t path_B {} +

# 2.
find path_A -name "*AAA*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} path_B
```

People would be confused,

1. why need mv `-t` (I mean, through a [for loop pipe] you can use `mv {} some_path` ，just like what you wrote without pipe )
2. why exec or | xargs is write in that way , xargs need much more options, but they are actually no need in many computer language 。
3. why I can't use  `ls ... mv -t path_B {} +`  , or `ls | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} path_B` ,  in other words , why it doesn't work after I change to another command ?
4. Why I failed when change `mv` to `7z` :  `find path_A -name '*AAA*' -exec 7z -t {} +`  ?

NOTE: Above are not question, just examples!!

---

**I asked this question for a common and simple way to cope for loop pipe .
Is there a simple and common way to do:**

```
# 0
command with option (usually you use a command like this)

# 1
command with option [for loop pipe] command with option | command with option
# 2
command with option [for loop pipe] command with option | command with option [for loop pipe] command with option
# 3 
....
```

So you don't need change `command with option`  when you use [for loop pipe] . This would be much convenient for daily use .

#### Update

I put all the example just want to say normal way is confusing when different comand has it own style to cope with multiline input, it would need `exec` or `xargs` or some else options . if we have a `for pipe` **command** which can connect two command with option . It would be much easy to use

I mean, if you are using an advanced language. For example python,

```py
def pipe(x, func, *func_options):
    return func(x, *func_options)

def forloop_pipe(x, func, *func_options):   
    return [func(i, *func_options) for i in x.split('\n')]


def ls(*options)
    pass

def mv(*options)
    pass

a = ls('*.txt') 
b = forloop_pipe(a, mv, '/home')
```

This is a very simple example with a lot of flaws, but it explains what I'm trying to get in bash command .

Comment: What is your question? Please focus more. Regarding 1.: You don't need `-t`, but then you can only handle one argument at a time and you need to end your `-exec` with `\;` instead of `+`.

Comment: Or use `shopt -s globstar` instead of `find`: `mv **/*AAA* target_dir` or `mv -t target_dir **/*AAA*`.

Comment: @pLumo I have highlight the question. The key is common way , not just find or someting else,  I need a common simple for loop pipe .

Comment: there is no such thing, every command is different.

Comment: ... in particular, in reference to your Q4, the `mv` command's `-t` specifies a **target directory** whereas the `7z` command's `-t` is for setting the **archive type**

Comment: @steeldriver @pLumo  I mean we use `7z e xxx.7z`  for daily use,  but `ls | 7z e` doesn't work , because of `|` is not for loop pipe . One would also failed  if he try `xargs` or `-exec` looked like for loop pipe somewhere .   Same as we usually `mv xxx  yyy` , we don't need `-t` , but as I remember it would failed . Why can't just like `command with option [for loop pipe] mv {} yyy` as usually ?

Comment: no it won't fail if you make sure that `{}` is **one** argument and not many! a pipe **is not** a loop, it has nothing to do with a loop. Why do you think that? `xargs` creates a loop if necessary from the input, but a pipe is not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is a straight answer to the question (there are much more than one questions), but I think you are asking for something like:

- `for` loop with *command substitution* or
- `while` loop with *process substitution*.

### `for` loop with `$(command substitution)`

[Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) allows the output of a command to replace the command itself. We can combine this functionality with the `for` loop in this way:

```bsh
for item in "$(find . -type f)"
do
    echo "$item" | tee -a ./"file-list.txt"
done
```

### `while` loop with `<(process substitution)`

[Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename. We can combine this functionality with the `while` loop, by the help of the built in `read`, in this way:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r item
do
    echo "$item" | tee -a ./"file-list.txt"
done < <(find . -type f)
```

Within the final part `< <(find . -type f)`, the first `<` means the stdin of the while `loop` and `<(find . -type f)` will be treated as a file. More about the construction `IFS= read -r line` you can read in [this great post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/201297) of Stéphane Chazelas.

You can achieve the same as the above by using pipe instead of *process substitution* (but this option is not preferred, because it could cause errors):

```bsh
find . -type f | while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "$file" | tee -a ./"file-list.txt"
done
```

### Pipe the output of a loop to another command

Further we can pipe or redirect the output of the loop to another command or function:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
    # Compose the name of the new file
    DIR="$(dirname "${item}")"
    FILE_NAME="$(basename "${item}")"
    NEW_FILE_NAME="new-${FILE_NAME}"

    # move the file and suppress the potential output 
    # of the 'mv' command by redirecting it to a log file 
    mv "${item}" "${DIR}/${NEW_FILE_NAME}" >>/tmp/mv-loop.log 2>&1

    # output the name of the new file in order to be processed 
    # by the next (piped) command
    printf '%b' "${DIR}/${NEW_FILE_NAME}"'\0'
done < <(find . -type f -print0) | xargs -0 -I{} 7z a -t7z "the_archive_name.7z" {}
```

Note within the above example a null delimiters is used everywhere:

- `find . -print0`,
- `IFS= read -r -d '' item` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677566/6543935),
- `printf '%b' a'\0'b` - [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223837/201297),
- `xargs -0` (in this case we do not actually need `-I{}` and `{}` within the `xargs` command).

This example will move (rename) all files recursively, but within the archive the directory structure wont appear.

Comment: Yeah, for/while loop is the common way. Maybe I didn't explain well, I put all the examle just want to say normal way is confusing when different comand has it own style cope with multiline input, it would need `exec` or `xargs` or some else options .  if we have  a `for pipe` **command**  which can connect  two `command with option` . It would be much easy to use .

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple and common way to do

**Answer: No, every command is different.**

---

Regarding your questions:

1. You don't need `-t`, but then `mv` will run for each file, which will be a lot slower. You need to end your `-exec` with `\;` instead of `+`.
2. A pipe has nothing to do with a `for` loop, a pipe sends *stdout* from left side of the pipe to *stdin* on the right side. `xargs` reads from *stdin* (or from a file with `-a` option) and runs a command with arguments taken from the input.
3. `ls` has no `-exec` option. `ls` **will** work with `xargs`, but not with `xargs -0` because `ls` has no option for NULL delimited output. That is also why [you should not use `ls` with pipes at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) (file names are allowed to have newlines).
4. For `mv`, `-t` is **target directory**, while for `7z` it is **archive type**, why do you think it should work?

For me it seems you're using commands you do not really understand. This won't work for any programming or scripting language.

---

Btw: You should use `xargs` with `-r` option to avoid issues with empty input.

Comment: Please see my update. Maybe I didn't explain well, I put all the examle just want to say normal way is confusing when different comand has it own style to cope with multiline input, it would need `exec` or `xargs` or some else options . if we have a `for pipe` **command** which can connect two `command with option` . It would be much easy to use

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your answer is `xargs -n 1`

See this example:  1 only line (loop generated for gzip):

```
ls | grep -i '.csv'  | xargs -n 1 gzip
```

or

```
ls  | grep -i '.gz'  | xargs -n 1 gunzip
```